Power BI - Balance on future date
I'm looking to create a code that allows me to get a value from the below
If I have a balance of £1 on a Future date to then give me a "Close" Value
IF [Balance] = £1 on [Future date] = "Close" else Blank
Learning power BI desktop coding

Please add some sample data with your expected output.

maybe you can try to create a column
column= if ([Balance]=1 && [Date]>today(), "Close"))
